# Is it possible to have a hybrid case-control cohort study?

Tags: case-control-study, case-cohort

In a cohort study, you take 500 people and tell them to smoke cigarettes and you take 500 people and tell them not to smoke cigarettes: you then wait to see how many people in the future get cancer in both groups. Here, you are actively conducting a study. Cohort studies are better because in theory you have more control over the study (e.g. more ability to correct for cofounders) and therefore can attribute causality much easier. However, cohort studies are harder because they require more money/time to conduct the study and require ethics approvals (e.g. its not ethical to ask people to start smoking).

In a case control study, you are given a pre-assembled dataset with 500 people who smoke cigarettes and 500 people who dont smoke cigarettes. Then, you check (no experiment, just straight up check/lookup in the dataset) how many of them get cancer and how many dont get cancer. Here, you are passively conducting a study. Case control studies are less powerful because you are analyzing data that has already been collected and have less room to ask questions on how the data was collected (e.g. what types of cofounders might have been present). But they are easier in the sense that they do not require you to conduct an experiment.

I was wondering, is it possible to mix both of these studies together? For instance, can I take groups of people that smoke cigarettes and people who dont smoke cigarettes (i.e. I dont tell them to start smoking) .... and then wait to see who develops cancer and who doesn't? This way I have the best of both worlds: less ethics/time/money concerns and more causality power?